# Restart the switch case statement

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement

hope i can found help here , in fact im design program to make user enter string values contains 0s or 1s and then menu appear to help user to chose from 4 option put my problem i cant return the menu to display after first use because the program cannot run any choices after fist select ...
Thank you again

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 0s or 1s Numbers  ");
    String binaryString = input.nextLine();// user must enter string value contains 0 or 1 
    convert.displayMenu();// call the display menu which contains 4 choices
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);// the user select the 1 option from 4
    int select = input2.nextInt(); // to save what user enter it 
    // here is the switch statement im use it 
    switch (select) {
        case 1:
            input2.equals(1);
            convert.getBinary(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
         break;
        case 2:
            input2.equals(2);
            convert.convertBtD(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            input2.equals(2);
            convert.convertBtO(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
            break ;
        case 4:
            break;
    }
    while(select != 4);
    }
```

Comment: It seems like your switch statement needs to be inside of a while loop checking if the scanner has input, maybe `while(input2.nextInt()) {...}`

Comment: Thank you paul put the loop while running  the case dosent work  after first choice

Answer (score 3):

This loop restarts the switch/case statement:

```
inputloop: while(true) {
  int select = input2.nextInt();
  switch (select) {
    case 1:
        input2.equals(1);
        convert.getBinary(binaryString);
        break;
    case 2:
        input2.equals(2);
        convert.convertBtD(binaryString);
        break;
    case 3:
        input2.equals(2);
        convert.convertBtO(binaryString);
        break ;
    case 4:
        break inputloop;
  }
  convert.displayMenu();
}
```

This code could be rewritten in a way that the loop condition is `select != 4` but this one is more concise (from my point of view)

Comment: CoronA  Thank you the loop you use it its perfect and working good

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean startLoop = true;
While(startLoop) {
switch(choice) {
case 1:
break;
case 2:
break;
case 3://exitChoice
startLoop = false;
break;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method by itself like:

```
    public void menu(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 0s or 1s Numbers  ");
        String binaryString = input.nextLine();// user must enter string value contains 0 or 1 
        convert.displayMenu();// call the display menu which contains 4 choices
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);// the user select the 1 option from 4
        int select = input2.nextInt(); // to save what user enter it 
        // here is the switch statement im use it  switch (select) {
            case 1:
                input2.equals(1);
                convert.getBinary(binaryString);
                convert.displayMenu();
             break;
            case 2:
                input2.equals(2);
                convert.convertBtD(binaryString);
                convert.displayMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                input2.equals(2);
                convert.convertBtO(binaryString);
                convert.displayMenu();
                break ;
            case 4:
                break;

            case 5: 
                System.out.println("Exit Point");
                System.exit(0);
        } 
menu();
}
```

I just add this code into a method and add a call menu() at the end of the method. I also create case 5 in order to exit the application. Its your logic how to do it right but you got main outline to achieve this :)

Comment: Thank you Sarz i will try it too

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be implemented like this:

```
    while(1){
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);// the user select the 1 option from 4
    int select = input2.nextInt(); // to save what user enter it 
    switch(select)
    {
        case 1:
            input2.equals(1);
            convert.getBinary(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            input2.equals(2);
            convert.convertBtD(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            input2.equals(2);
            convert.convertBtO(binaryString);
            convert.displayMenu();
            break ;
        case 4:
            break;
    }
    if(select == 4)
        break;
```

}